# Howto get a random object from DB?

Tags: jpa, random, playframework

For more dynamism, I would like to add a random part on my app. 
Here is what I would have done in other techs, and what is not working in play :

```
long id = JPA.execute("select id from Realisation r order by RANDOM() LIMIT 1");
```

And here is the stack :

```
unexpected token: LIMIT near line 1, column 55
```

Comments :

- Either in app or database, makes no difference to me.
- About hundred "realisations" in database.
- All I need is there ID, no need for full object.
- MySQL database behind it all.

**EDIT**

After a little investigation, here is how I've done it :

- Define jpa.dialect in application.conf : `jpa.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect`
- Fetch a complete object instead of just id with classic Model utilities :

`Realisation r = Realisation.find("order by RAND()").first();`

Comment: This is not necessarily an answer but it looks like there is some good info here: http://akinas.com/pages/en/blog/mysql_random_row/

Comment: Yeah, thanks, but the problem was to specific to JPA/HQL and not MySQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a little investigation, here is how I've done it. Define jpa.dialect in application.conf :

`jpa.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect`

Fetch a complete object instead of just id with classic Model utilities :

```
Realisation r = Realisation.find("order by RAND()").first();
```

Not the best way possible, since I only need the ID and not the complete object. Anyway, I have no other solution. If anyone has one for just the ID I will take it.

Answer (score 1):

There is no "limit" clause in JPQL, what you need is paging. You can use Query.setMaxResults instead if this is a JPQL query, which is not entirely clear in the post.

Comment: Indeed it is not explicity said, but this is a playframework tagged question. Play! adds a layer upon JPA/Hibernate for more simplicity. And I don't think setMaxResults is available trough their layer.